# Proof of Cauchy's determinant identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading [Matrix Analysis 2nd](https://books.google.com/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC&source=gbs_similarbooks&redir_esc=y). Page 66 gives the proof of Caucuh's determinant identity as follow:
[image: Example]

where $(1.3.23)$ is as follow:
[image: 1.3.23]

I am very confused about these questions:

1. How does second identity make sense? What does $\lambda_i$ stand for?
2. The $\lambda_i$ should be mulitplied into $I$ in the third identity. But it did not happen. Why?

Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance! I am very very confused...

Comment: The identity itself is fairly well-known: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514408/matrix-determinant-lemma-with-adjugate-matrix?rq=1 . Not sure about that proof. I guess $\lambda_i\left(K\right)$ means the $i$-th eigenvalue of $K$ in some order.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think the OP actually meant to ask why the second and the third equality signs are correct.

Comment: The second equality sign follows because the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues. The third holds because the eigenvalues of $I + B$ are $1 + \mu$ where $\mu$ ranges over the eigenvalues of $B$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I know the det of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues, but it seems that $I + A^{-1}xy^T$ is still a matrix...

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think I misunderstand the notation. Could you tell me which matrix does $\lambda_i$ correspond to?

Comment: Yes, but its eigenvalues are $1 + y^TA^{-1}x$ (one time) and $1$ (many times), so the product of these eigenvalues is $1 + y^TA^{-1}x$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see. $\lambda_i$ is not specific value here, it is a function... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. if $B$, $C$ are $n\times n$ matrices then

$$\det (\lambda I_n + B C) = \det(\lambda I_n + C B)$$

2. If $k \le n$, $B$ is $n\times k$, $C$ is $k\times n$ then

$$\det( \lambda I_n + B C) = \lambda^{n-k} \det ( \lambda I_k + C B)$$

How to prove 2. from 1.: Consider the $n\times n$ matrices $\tilde B$, $\tilde C$ obtained as follows: complete $B$ with $n-k$ columns of $0$ to the right, and $C$ with $n-k$ rows of zero at the bottom. Now check that $\tilde B \cdot \tilde C = B\cdot C$, while $\tilde C \cdot \tilde B$ is $n\times n$ with the $ k \times k$ block $C\cdot B$ and $0$ in rest. The conclusions follows now.

To prove 1. We have

$$\det C \cdot \det (\lambda I_n + B C) = \det ( C( \lambda I_n + B C)) = \det ( ( \lambda I_n + C B) C) = \det ( \lambda I_n + C B) \cdot \det C$$
and if this is considered as a polynomial identity, we can simplify with $\det C\ne 0$.

Form 2.  taking $\lambda=1$ we get

3. If  $B$ is $n \times k$ and $C$ is $k\times n$ then

$$\det ( I_n + B C) = \det( I_k + C B)$$

Now assume that $A$ is $n\times n$, $B$ is $n\times k$, and $C$ is $k\times n$. We get from 3. (assume for now $A$ invertible)

$$\det (A + B C) = \det ( A( I_n + A^{-1} B C) = \det A \det (I_n + (A^{-1} B) C) =\\= \det A \cdot \det(I_k + C A^{-1} B)$$

Now assume that $k=1$. Then $\det (I_k + C A^{-1} B) = 1 + C A^{-1} B$, so we get
$$\det A ( 1 + C A^{-1} B) = \det A + C (\det A \cdot A^{-1}) B$$

Note that $\det A \cdot A^{-1} = \operatorname{adj} A$. Therefore we get

4. For $A$ $n\times n$, $B$ $\ n\times 1$, $C$ $\ 1\times n$

$$\det( A + B C) = \det A + C \cdot \operatorname{adj}(A)\cdot B$$

Note that by density the property holds for all $A$ $\ n\times n$.

$\bf{Added:}$ The result above is very similar to the formula for the determinant of a bordant matrix. So let $A$ be $n\times n$, $x$ an $n\times 1$, $y$ $\ 1\times n$, $\alpha$ a constant. Consider the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix $\tilde A$ obtained from $A$ by bordering the row $n+1$ with $x$, column $n+1$ with $y$, and element $(n+1, n+1)$ to be $\alpha$. Then we have

$$\det \tilde A = \alpha \cdot \det A - y \operatorname{adj} A x$$
(notice the $-$ sign) (the Cauchy expansion)

May assume $\alpha\ne 0$, then $\alpha=1$. Then, we can reduce the last row to $0$ ( except the entry $\alpha$) Then the $n\times n$ block becomes $A - x \cdot y$, and we apply the known result.